# Efficient way to refactor a method argument to its member function?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

When writing Java, I often have the need to refactor a method signature by replacing an object with the return value of its member function. For example:

I have an method originally written like this:

```
main() {
  foo(user);
}

private void foo(User user) {
    String userName = user.getName();
}

class User {
 String name;
 // getter and setter
}
```

After a while, I realized that I can just pass in the userName directly:

```
main() {
   foo(user.getName());
}

private void foo(String name) {
   String userName = name;
}
```

---

**Question**: In intelliJ idea (2016.2.1), is there any efficient way to do such refactoring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the caret on `String userName =` or `user.getName();` (it will provide a different result) and press `Refactor | Extract | Parameter` (shortcut `Ctrl + Alt + P`)

Comment: Yes it is working. What if I have multiple usage of user.getName() within the method? If I do the above, only one of them is extracted. Can I extract them all together?

Comment: Yes, if you put a caret on `user.getName();`